# Why does my Xbox One turn on randomly (and how do I make it stop)?

Tags: xbox-one

This has been happening for some time now. My Xbox One will turn on randomly. Sometimes, it doesn't make the sound when it turns itself on, I just happen to notice the light on my Xbox One and Kinect are both on.  Other times it does make the sound.

I **do not** have the "Instant On" feature enabled, nor do I have the "Keep my games & apps up to date" feature enabled.

I **do** use the Xbox app on Windows 10 as well as on my phone, but as far as I know, these cannot turn the console on (they can connect to the console, however it needs to be on first before they can).

What could be causing this? <s>I have considered the Kinect possibly turning the Xbox on, but why would it?</s> My Kinect is no longer connected to my Xbox and it still happens.

**Edit One:**  This is still happening after numerous updates - 4 months later.

**Edit Two:** About 5 months later this is still going on.  Do Xbox One's have some sort of Wake on LAN feature that is hidden?  I'm beginning to wonder if it is attempting to download an update for the software similar to how Windows does.  I've experienced something very similar with my Windows 10 PC turning itself on to download an update (but not install it until I manually restart).

Comment: The console lights used to light up if a download was occurring while the xbox was off, im not sure if thats true anymore though. The white kinect light should only come on if the kinect is in listening mode though, AFAIK. Does it actually show the dashboard if the tv is on? Or are just the lights turning on?

Comment: The dashboard is there yes.  And I have that download feature disabled (keep games & apps up to date).

Comment: From personal experience, the Kinect is very touchy to voice commands. From my kitchen to my living room simply saying the words "something something ON" would turn on the Xbox.  Even if you do not believe that is the case, you could try turning the voice commands off?

Comment: Just for reference I can turn on my xbox from the xbox app in windows. Just to correct your comment that "they can connect to the console, however it needs to be on first before they can". Sadly I can't think of what would be causing this. I think even if the app turns it on (which I can think of no reason it would be) it still makes the turning on sound. Out of interest when you notice it is on if you turn your TV to your xbox what is it showing? ie is it showing the dashboard or something else?

Comment: @Chris I've noticed sometimes it does produce the turning on sound now.  I'm going to edit that into the question.  Also, how do you turn it on via the Windows App?

Comment: @TimmyJim: ON the xbox app you can connect to your xbox. In that area it has an option to turn it on if it is off. It may be that it will only work if you have suitable settings on your xbox to allow it to wake on lan.

Comment: Xbox can be powered on through voice command as noted above by @Mumford451 I have had this personally happen when in another room watching tv, and they said something about "putting a box on" or something to the effect, and it got picked up from the Kinect. I then heard my xbox power on noise. Went into my room and it was powered on.

Comment: @C-dizzle I don't have the instant on feature enabled.  It should therefore be impossible to turn the Xbox on via voice commands since the power supply isn't on (it has an orange light instead of white) and the Kinect is not listening.  I've tested this as well.

Comment: This will probably be something to take to Xbox support itself, Arqade can only do minimal troubleshooting when it comes to these sort of things. You may very well have a faulty system you need to send in.

Comment: @Rapitor it could be faulty, but I wanted to see if anyone else who experiences this has a fix or knows why it does this. Since its not that big of a problem, I don't feel like sending it in and being Xboxless for weeks and paying for something that otherwise isn't impacting how the Xbox performs.

Comment: For what it's worth, something similar used to happen to my Xbox 360 as well. Don't know if there was any solution there, but this may be an issue that goes beyond the Xbox One

Comment: I'm trying to deal with Xbox support to get this resolved, but so far nothing they have suggested has helped.
Just out of curiosity, do you use an HDMI switch? I do, and sometimes I wonder if that's the issue.

Comment: @Melllvar nope. Just straight hdmi to my monitor.

Comment: I have the same issue, and I'm seeing more and more of this written up elsewhere. I get the distinct feeling this is the RROD for the new generation of Xboxen.

Comment: @TimmyJim hi, did you ever find the cause, or a way to stop it from turning on?

Comment: @AJPerez nope! And its been years since I've had my Xbox One even setup... I suppose that solves the problem technically... but when I last had it connected, it sure enough would still do this.

Answer (score 3):

I have had this happen to me many times now, I think it may have started when I connected some external HDDs to my Xbox for additional storage. Although that is just a theory that the HDDs might have something to do with it. My Xbox is also set to be fully turned off and no background updates.

My solution is simple yet very effective, buy a power / surge protector bar that has a switch which can turn the whole power bar on and off, ideally you want to have a power bar that has lights to indicate if it is on or off.

Next plug your Xbox in to that power bar which is dedicated to the use of your Xbox, last but not least turn the power bar on when you want to play your Xbox games, then shutdown your Xbox via the software interface when you are done playing your games and when the Xbox is fully off, turn off the power bar to kill all power to the Xbox, that way it cannot power on since the power bar will give no power to the Xbox.

Comment: +1 I too have an external HDD hooked up to it.  I hadn't considered that.  Unfortunately, my Xbox (along with out devices) is connected to an uninterrupted power supply (battery backup). I would like to avoid having to switch that off is possible.

Comment: I do not have an external HDD hooked up, and mine still does this sometimes. Just putting in my 2 cents

Comment: Are you connected through an HDMI switch by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

Is there something near the power button?  Since the console doesn't have a physical power button, certain things falling/resting in front of the button may trigger it.

Additionally, is anything hitting the power button on one of the controllers?  The controllers powering on can power on the console which they are synced to.

If this persists, I'd contact Microsoft as you may have some sort of a connection problem with the power button.

Comment: Nothing is causing my controllers to turn themselves on, as they are all off when the console turns itself on.  Nothing is near the power button either for the console.

Answer (score 1):

Xbox One supports [HDMI CEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_Electronics_Control) standard, which is enabled by default (as opposed to PS4 where it seems off by default afaik). If you have a newer TV which also supports this feature, and the XBox is connected using HDMI then it may be turning on whenever you turn on the TV.

Answer (score 0):

my xbox was doing the same thing so i did some research and after awhile of digging i heard ants can be inside so i went too my xbox and moved it a little and millions of ants came out. it took awhile but i finally got they all out and my xbox works fine now. hope this helps :P

Comment: Ants??? Never heard of that - nor do I think this is the case. I feel I would have seen ants around my house for this to even happen.

Answer (score -4):

Unplug your Xbox from the surge protector

Comment: Can you provide any further information as to why this may be the issue?

Comment: The question does not mention a surge protector. Why do you think this is a working solution?